# value is always set to 1 even if the input is 0

Tags: c++

ok so i writ this little code in c++. keep in mind i just started learning c++ so this problem confused me a lot
when i run this code in code blocks (

```
using namespace std;

int Answer;
int main()
{
cout << "yo, are u male?"<< endl;

cin >>Answer;

if (Answer = 1){
    cout << "ur male"<< endl;
} else {
    cout <<"ur female"<< endl;
    }

cout <<Answer;
}
)
```

the answer value is always set to one even if i type 0
i tried coding another if statement for the answer value if it was 0 but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `=` operator is an *assignment operator* and it sets value of left operand to value of right operand. Therefore the value of `Answer` becomes `1` thanks to `Answer = 1`.

You should use `==` operator to check equality.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `==` operator in your code, as `=` operators does the job of assigning values.

```
using namespace std;

int Answer;
int main()
{
cout << "yo, are u male?"<< endl;

cin >>Answer;

if (Answer == 1){
    cout << "ur male"<< endl;
} else {
    cout <<"ur female"<< endl;
    }

cout <<Answer;
}
)
```